# How do I customize physical storage of class properties with Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

#### Background

I work on a 15+ years old Java application that has user-customizable entity types with custom fields. It uses Hibernate for mapping Java classes to a database. We support multiple database vendors but most of our users have Microsoft SQL Server. To allow the custom fields the database schema employs an [EAV model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). In other words, the entity class contains a set of maps

```
private Map<Integer, String> strings;
private Map<Integer, Integer> integers;
private Map<Integer, Double> doubles;
```

where the integer key indicates the field identifier. Any entity in the system can arbitrarily  contain values for any of the fields that the customer has defined.

The corresponding Hibernate mappings for the maps look like this:

```
<map name="integers" table="Entity_Integers" access="field">
    <key column="entityId" />
    <map-key type="int" column="fieldId" />
    <element type="int" column="value" />
</map>
```

The downside to this is that when users design complex queries that fetch, filter and sort on many fields, you get one SQL JOIN for every field referenced. For some users that have a lot of data, MSSQL's execution planner breaks down and chooses very poor plans, leading to horrible performance. We have been trying many different ideas over the past couple of years to work around this bottleneck, but at the root of it is the EAV model and ditching it entirely is not an option for this generation of the application.

However, I have had an insight that my intuition tells me will all but fix the problem, at least until we can afford a more serious redesign. Instead of having a huge table containing every value of every field and entity, we dynamically create one table for each distinct field. I believe that would greatly improve the precision of MSSQL's table statistics, and reduce table sizes by avoiding the extra "fieldId" column. As a consequence it should be much easier for MSSQL to choose a good execution plan while simultaneously reducing the cache footprint of the tables. In fact, removing the fieldId column makes it impossible for MSSQL to even generate the execution plans that we are seeing now. It would mean creating some 300 additional tables, but I don't think MSSQL will have a problem with that.

I don't *know* that this will solve the problem, but I think it's worth making a test to see what performance we get.

#### Question

So with that in mind, what I wonder is how I can control the way the entity field data is represented in the database. I want to change the way the maps are sent and fetched to/from the database so that, instead of having the field-ID key become the value for a column in a huge EAV table, the field ID would control the name of the table that gets used to insert a row containing only entity ID and field value (which field is implicit from the table name).

For example, if entity with ID 1005 has an integer value 25 for field ID 5, it currently gets stored as a row in the Entity_Integers table:

| entityId | fieldId | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1005 | 5 | 25 |

Instead, I want it to get stored as a row in a table named Entity_Field_5:

| entityId | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1005 | 25 |

I would also need a mechanism to keep track of which fields are set for an entity, so I'll know where to go when reading an entity in its entirety. Is this kind of mapping possible to do with Hibernate, and how? I would need to create new tables while system is running.

Comment: If you're contemplating defining tables at runtime, why not ditch the EAV and simply create tables dynamically for each customized entity? You could use then use [dynamic entities](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic), for instance

Comment: @crizzis sure that may be an alternative, but how do I do it with Hibernate? I googled my way to this - is that a good way? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#dynamic-model
On the surface it seems kind of limited in terms of what types you can use as values

Comment: Well, TBH I never used it, so I can't really comment. The docs don't say anything about defining the mapping files dynamically, though, so that might be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic model example you found is just that, an example: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#dynamic-model

The Hibernate mapping is pretty flexible and is the predecessor of the annotation model, so you can map everything you can already do in Java. One problem is that the HBM mappings will go away at some point in favor of an extension to the JPA orm.xml mapping model. Every schema change would also require a rebuild of a `SessionFactory` with new models which also isn't that easy. So if you really want to do this, I would suggest you try to use the mapping model classes (PersistentClass, etc.) directly instead which is more future-proof.

I will advise against this approach anyway as that will not solve your underlying performance issue. If you want good performance, you should create dedicated types, tables and mappings for that purpose. If some parts are extensible, this can be modeled through a JSON or EAV model, but the performance of querying against that will usually still not be great. With a JSON approach you can at least create indexes for certain access patterns and don't need all these joins, but with EAV your only option to improve performance is to use pre-joined tables (Oracle table cluster) or a materialized view. Since incremental view maintenance is not a thing on any database other than Oracle and even that doesn't support outer joins for that, you are probably out of luck to get good performance with that model.

Doing many joins is certainly doable for a database, but there are limits. Most databases will stop their cost based optimization at a certain join amount and just apply rule based optimization which might not produce what you'd like.

As far as I can see, the way out of your performance issues is to use a JSON type which is supported on most modern databases in one way or another. You can map it a `String` if you want, it doesn't really matter. For accessing parts, you can add access functions to Hibernate. You could use a library like Blaze-Persistence which provides JSON access functions for various databases out of the box: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/core/manual/en_US/#json_get

From there on, you just need to add indexes for certain filters if customers complain.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your thorough reply. Are you implying that the JPA mapping-model extensions will not support creating new mappings at runtime?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "support creating new mappings at runtime". In the end, using a runtime generated mapping model boils down to creating a new persistence unit / session factory and you can always do that, but it's not really convenient nor pretty useful in your case IMO since your model can change at any time. You can still do this, create XML on the fly and rebuild the persistence unit, but I would suggest you go with the JSON solution for all the mentioned advantages that solution has.